# How to add CSS properties by JavaScript when the input match the right code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a master's student, and I'm working on my project, which is a browser game, and I am stuck. The problem that I face is as follows.
If someone writes CSS code in the gold input box and matches this code ((.alignCulomn{display: flex;})) So the alignment of the text div should align from this
[image]
to this
[image]
JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("codeAnwsoer").onsubmit = function () {
  let colCon = document.getElementsByClassName("columnContanter");
  let cssCode = document.getElementById("csscode").value;
  let cssCodeRg = /.alignCulomn{display: flex;}/gi;
  let applyCode = cssCodeRg.match(cssCode);

  if (applyCode === true) {
    console.log((colCon.style.display = "flex"));
  } else {
    document.getElementById("csscode").value = "wrong";
  }
};
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --text-icon-cd: black;
  --theme-color: #ffc648;
  --border-radius: 12px;
  --transition: all 0.5s ease;
  --background-cd: rgb(226, 226, 226);
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  background-color: var(--background-cd);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

/* Sidebar Code */

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 78px;
  background-color: var(--theme-color);
  padding: 6px 14px;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

.sidebar.active {
  width: 240px;
}

.sidebar .logo_content .logo {
  color: var(--text-icon-cd);
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

.sidebar.active .logo_content .logo {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.logo_content .logo i {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.logo_content .logo .logo_name {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.sidebar #btn {
  position: absolute;
  color: var(--text-icon-cd);
  left: 50%;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.sidebar.active #btn {
  left: 90%;
}

.sidebar ul {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.sidebar ul li {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 5px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.sidebar ul li .tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  left: 122px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  height: 35px;
  width: 122px;
  background-color: var(--theme-color);
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar.active ul li .tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar ul li:hover .tooltip {
  transition: var(--transition);
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50%;
}

.sidebar ul li input {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffd373;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: var(--text-icon-cd);
}

.sidebar ul li .fa-magnifying-glass {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  color: var(--text-icon-cd);
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

.sidebar ul li .fa-magnifying-glass:hover {
  background-color: var(--text-icon-cd);
  color: var(--theme-color);
}

.sidebar ul li a {
  color: var(--text-icon-cd);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: var(--theme-color);
  background-color: var(--text-icon-cd);
}

.sidebar ul li i {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar .links_name {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.sidebar.active .links_name {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.sidebar .profile_content {
  position: absolute;
  color: var(--text-icon-cd);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar .profile_content .profile {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 6px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar.active .profile_content .profile {
  background-color: #dba124;
}

.profile_content .profile .profile_details {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar.active .profile .profile_details {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.profile .profile_details img {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
}

.profile .profile_details .name_job {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.profile .profile_details .name {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.profile .profile_details .job {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.profile #log_out {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 5px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  min-width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background-color: #dba124;
}

.sidebar.active .profile #log_out {
  left: 88%;
}

.sidebar.active .profile #log_out {
  background-color: none;
}

.home_content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
  left: 78px;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

.home_content .text {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--text-icon-cd);
  margin: 12px;
}

.sidebar.active ~ .home_content {
  width: calc(100% - 240px);
  left: 240px;
}
/* Sidebar Code */

.rectanglecontainer {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 180px;
  padding-left: 343px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
}

.infoRectangle {
  background-color: var(--text-icon-cd);
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  position: relative;
}

.codeRectangle {
  background-color: var(--text-icon-cd);
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
}

#csscode {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: var(--theme-color);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-width: 5px;
  padding: 0 0 150px 0;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 450px;
}

#csscode:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  outline-style: none;
  border-color: var(--theme-color);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-width: 5px;
  padding: 0 0 150px 0;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 450px;
  caret-color: white;
}

.boy {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 240px;
  user-select: none;
}

.rectanglenext {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px var(--background-cd) solid;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 70px;
  left: 400px;
}

.reg {
  background-color: var(--background-cd);
  position: absolute;
  right: 750px;
  bottom: 80px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#ch {
  color: var(--background-cd);
  background-color: var(--text-icon-cd);
  border: solid 2px var(--background-cd);
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 76px;
  left: 405px;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}

#ch2 {
  color: var(--background-cd);
  background-color: var(--text-icon-cd);
  border: solid 2px var(--background-cd);
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 76px;
  left: 1105px;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}

p:not(.p) {
  color: var(--background-cd);
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pazzle {
  background-color: white;
  height: 550px;
  width: 1200px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 360px;
  top: 20px;
}

.columnContanter {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* this line will make the alignment from the flex to block or block to flex */
  /* display: flex; */
}

.calumn1,
.calumn2,
.calumn3 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.calumn1 {
  background-color: #dba124;
}

.calumn2 {
  background-color: rgb(11, 172, 118);
}

.calumn3 {
  background-color: rgb(3, 158, 158);
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Web Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css" />
    <!-- Lato -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!-- Lato -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="logo_content">
          <div class="logo">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-gamepad"></i>
            <div class="logo_name">CodinGame</div>
          </div>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav_list">
          <li>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
            <span class="tooltip">Search</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
              <span class="links_name">User</span>
            </a>
            <span class="tooltip">User</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-sliders"></i>
              <span class="links_name">Options</span>
            </a>
            <span class="tooltip">Options</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-wide-short"></i>
              <span class="links_name">Level</span>
            </a>
            <span class="tooltip">Level</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="profile_content">
          <div class="profile">
            <div class="profile_details">
              <img src="Images/0-puss-in-boots.jpg" alt="" />
              <div class="name_job">
                <div class="name">Ali Mushrif</div>
                <div class="job">Web Designer</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket" id="log_out"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="theall">
          <div class="rectanglecontainer">
            <div class="infoRectangle">
              <p><b id="name">Let's Start</b>.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="codeRectangle"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="pazzleContainer">
            <div class="pazzle">
              <div class="columnContanter">
                <div class="calumn1">
                  <h1>Column 1</h1>
                  <p class="p">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Beatae ducimus aliquam nulla deleniti incidunt, quos natus
                    ex sunt in molestiae fugit ab? Debitis, repellendus ut
                    magnam earum est vel cupiditate soluta quos eveniet deserunt
                    nemo ipsum at quis in dolorem. Quaerat nisi sequi
                    dignissimos eaque dolores magni similique praesentium sed?
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="calumn2">
                  <h1>Column 2</h1>
                  <p class="p">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Voluptates repellat delectus voluptas voluptatem ducimus
                    sequi quos aliquam nesciunt esse expedita optio voluptate
                    modi nostrum, doloribus et pariatur porro dolorem aspernatur
                    illo nemo dignissimos unde debitis, similique eius. Quisquam
                    voluptatum commodi, sunt quidem, iure perferendis sed et
                    iusto, distinctio corporis corrupti.
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="calumn3">
                  <h1>Column 3</h1>
                  <p class="p">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Perferendis dicta doloribus mollitia eaque tempora, officiis
                    nihil pariatur praesentium! Animi maxime, molestiae ducimus
                    expedita nisi veritatis natus amet laboriosam cum mollitia
                    minima, consectetur aut possimus? Minima labore sed ullam
                    animi nam, impedit atque recusandae nulla quis et expedita
                    sunt facere ipsa!
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="Images/Final.svg" class="boy" alt="" />
      <input type="button" onclick="changeText()" value="Next Level" id="ch" />
      <form id="codeAnwsoer" action="" method="dialog">
        <input type="text" maxlength="30" id="csscode" name="the-code" />
        <input class="reg" type="submit" value="Run" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I made you a snippet. The HTML is not valid and the submit button not visible, There is no changeText function present either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've edited your js code to this :

```
document.getElementById("codeAnwsoer").onsubmit = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let colCon = document.querySelector(".columnContanter");
  let cssCode = document.getElementById("csscode").value;
  let cssCodeRg =/.alignCulomn{display: flex;}/gi;
  let applyCode = cssCode.match(cssCodeRg)
  if (applyCode) {
    colCon.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("csscode").value = "wrong";
  }
};
```

A couple of tips to help you better understand my answer:

1. In javascript *string.match* does not return a boolean value it returns an array containing the matches and if no match is found it returns null so to check if there is a match or not you can't use *"applyCode === true"*
2. *getElementsByClassName()* returns an array of objects and Since you only have one div with the class of 'columnContanter' it's better to use *document.querySelector()*
3. Use *preventDefault* to stop the browser's default behaviour

Answer (score 1):

tip: you should work on naming things better.
what i did: saved the answer in a string. `cssCodeRg`
getting value from the input `cssCode`.
placing a click event listener on `submitbtn`
then setting condition for true or false for validation
this is the text user has to put to make it happen.`.alignCulomn{display: flex;}`.you should change it and think something better like `display:flex;`only.
i hope i could help

```js
let colCon = document.querySelector(".columnContanter");
    let cssCode = document.getElementById("csscode");
    let cssCodeRg = ".alignCulomn{display: flex;}";
    let submitbtn = document.querySelector(".reg")


    submitbtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        event.preventDefault();
        cssCode = cssCode.value;
        if (cssCodeRg == cssCode) {
            colCon.style.display = "flex";

        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("csscode").value = "wrong";
        }


    })
```

```css
.columnContanter {
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        /* this line will make the alignment from the flex to block or block to flex */
    }

    .calumn1,
    .calumn2,
    .calumn3 {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 5px auto;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .calumn1 {
        background-color: #dba124;
    }

    .calumn2 {
        background-color: rgb(11, 172, 118);
    }

    .calumn3 {
        background-color: rgb(3, 158, 158);
    }

    .reg {
        width: 60px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #csscode {
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        font-size: 24px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="columnContanter">
        <div class="calumn1">
            <h1>Column 1</h1>
            <p class="p">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ducimus aliquam nulla deleniti incidunt,
                quos natus ex sunt in molestiae fugit ab? Debitis, repellendus ut magnam earum est vel cupiditate soluta
                quos eveniet deserunt nemo ipsum at quis
                in dolorem. Quaerat nisi sequi dignissimos eaque dolores magni similique praesentium sed?
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="calumn2">
            <h1>Column 2</h1>
            <p class="p">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates repellat delectus voluptas
                voluptatem ducimus sequi quos aliquam nesciunt esse expedita optio voluptate modi nostrum, doloribus et
                pariatur porro dolorem aspernatur illo nemo dignissimos
                unde debitis, similique eius. Quisquam voluptatum commodi, sunt quidem, iure perferendis sed et iusto,
                distinctio corporis corrupti.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="calumn3">
            <h1>Column 3</h1>
            <p class="p">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis dicta doloribus mollitia eaque
                tempora, officiis nihil pariatur praesentium! Animi maxime, molestiae ducimus expedita nisi veritatis
                natus amet laboriosam cum mollitia minima, consectetur
                aut possimus? Minima labore sed ullam animi nam, impedit atque recusandae nulla quis et expedita sunt
                facere ipsa!
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <img src="Images/Final.svg" class="boy" alt="" />
    <input type="button" onclick="changeText()" value="Next Level" id="ch" />
    <form id="codeAnwsoer" action="" method="dialog">
        <input type="text" maxlength="30" id="csscode" name="the-code" />
        <input class="reg" type="submit" value="Run" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are lot of things going wrong in your code.
Firsty you are using onsubmit try to

```
event.preventDefault()
```

In your code to avoid refreshing on submit
document.getElementsByClassName
Return a nodeList of elements which you have to iterate through you can't directly apply styles like try this

```
colCon[0].style.display
```

But I recommend you to use query selector method

```
documennt.querySelector('.class')
```

And second check your regex I am not master in regex but your regex contains `.` symbol which is a special character you should escape this `\.`